# Numpy optimization with Numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I have two sets of points on a sphere, labelled 'obj' and 'ps' in the code example below. I would like to identify all 'obj' points that are closer than a certain angular distance from a 'ps' point.

My take on this is to represent each point by a 3D unit vector, and to compare their dot products to cos(maximum separation). This can be done easily with numpy broadcasting, but in my application I have n_obj ~ 500,000 and n_ps ~ 50,000, so the memory requirements of broadcasting are too large. Below I have pasted my current take using numba. Can this be optimized further?

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

def gen_points(n):
    """
    generate random 3D unit vectors (not uniform, but irrelevant here)
    """
    vec = 2*np.random.rand(n,3)-1.
    vec_norm = normalize(vec)
    return vec_norm

#@jit(nopython=True)
@jit
def angdist_threshold_numba(vec_obj,vec_ps,cos_maxsep):
    """
    finds obj that are closer than maxsep to a ps
    """    
    nps = len(vec_ps)
    nobj = len(vec_obj)     

    #closeobj_all = []
    closeobj_all = np.empty(0)
    dotprod = np.empty(nobj)
    a = np.arange(nobj)
    for ps in range(nps):
        np.sum(vec_obj*vec_ps[ps],axis=1,out=dotprod)
        #closeobj_all.extend(a[dotprod > cos_maxsep])
        closeobj_all = np.append(closeobj_all, a[dotprod > cos_maxsep])  

    return closeobj_all


vec_obj = gen_points(50000) #in reality ~500,000
vec_ps = gen_points(5000) #in reality ~50,000
cos_maxsep = np.cos(0.003)

closeobj_all = np.unique(angdist_threshold_numba(vec_obj,vec_ps,cos_maxsep))
```

This is the performance using the test case given in the code:

```
%timeit np.unique(angdist_threshold_numba(vec_obj,vec_ps,cos_maxsep))
1 loops, best of 3: 4.53 s per loop
```

I have tried to speed it up using

```
@jit(nopython=True)
```

but this fails with

```
NotImplementedError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
(<class 'numba.ir.Expr'>, build_list(items=[]))
```

Edit: After a numba update to 0.26 the creation of the empty list fails even in the python mode. This can be fixed by replacing it with np.empty(0), and the .extend() with np.append(), see above. This almost doesn't change the performance.

According to https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/858 np.empty() is now supported in nopython mode, but I still can't run this with @jit(nopython = True):

```
TypingError: Internal error at <numba.typeinfer.CallConstraint object at 0x7ff3114a9310>
```

Comment: can't you just use cdist from scipy.spatial.distance? ie. distance.cdist(vec_obj, vec_ps, 'cosine')

Comment: It's fast, and it does what I need. But already with the numbers I used in the example, the 2D array returned by cdist uses ~2GB of memory. That means with the real size (10x larger along both axes), you run into the memory problem again.

Comment: then seems you're justified going the custom route. Since numba seems to be having issues with the list, could you try using a sparse matrix instead?

Comment: Replacing the list by an empty array yields the same performance in python mode (see edit), and also fails in the nopython mode. Are sparse matrices supported in nopython mode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlike `list.append` you should never call `numpy.append` in a loop! This is because even for appending a single element the whole array needs to be copied. Because you're only interested in the unique `obj` you could use a Boolean array to flag the matches found so far.

As for Numba, it works best if you write out all the loops. So for example:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def numba2(vec_obj, vec_ps, cos_maxsep):
    nps = vec_ps.shape[0]
    nobj = vec_obj.shape[0]
    dim = vec_obj.shape[1]
    found = np.zeros(nobj, np.bool_)
    for i in range(nobj):
        for j in range(nps):
            cos = 0.0
            for k in range(dim):
                cos += vec_obj[i,k] * vec_ps[j,k]
            if cos > cos_maxsep:
                found[i] = True
                break
    return found.nonzero()
```

The added benefit is that we can break out of the loop over the `ps` array as soon as we find a match to the current `obj`.

You can gain some more speed by specializing the function for 3 dimensional spaces. Also, for some reason, passing all arrays and relevant dimensions into a helper function results in another speedup:

```
def numba3(vec_obj, vec_ps, cos_maxsep):
    nps = len(vec_ps)
    nobj = len(vec_obj)
    out = np.zeros(nobj, bool)
    numba3_helper(vec_obj, vec_ps, cos_maxsep, out, nps, nobj)
    return np.flatnonzero(out)

@jit(nopython=True)
def numba3_helper(vec_obj, vec_ps, cos_maxsep, out, nps, nobj):
    for i in range(nobj):
        for j in range(nps):
            cos = (vec_obj[i,0]*vec_ps[j,0] + 
                   vec_obj[i,1]*vec_ps[j,1] + 
                   vec_obj[i,2]*vec_ps[j,2])
            if cos > cos_maxsep:
                out[i] = True
                break
    return out
```

Timings I get for 20,000 `obj` and 2,000 `ps`:

```
%timeit angdist_threshold_numba(vec_obj,vec_ps,cos_maxsep)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.99 s per loop
%timeit numba2(vec_obj, vec_ps, cos_maxsep)
1 loop, best of 3: 444 ms per loop
%timeit numba3(vec_obj, vec_ps, cos_maxsep)
10 loops, best of 3: 134 ms per loop
```

Comment: I must say I'm impressed. A factor 20 of speedup, and still a factor of 10 compared to the scipy.spatial.distance.cdist suggested in the comments above. Also very pedagogical! PS: Tried to make one cosmetic edit to the return of numba2 (adding a [0] for consistency), but SO wouldn't let me.

Comment: @user4319496 apologies if the tone was pedagogical.. I'm just surprised that this can't be done with a built-in. Since it seems it can't, there might be a worthy contribution to scipy to be made here - what you're doing isn't that unusual